# AutoCompleteTextView drop down always visible

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I want to make my AutoCompleteTextView to always show drop down list. Now it appears only when it is 3 letters written. How can i do that?

Comment: use threshold, the default is 3, however it has to be >= 1

Comment: how to set threshold...? setThreshold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
```

By default, when threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied.

Comment: great! don't forget to select it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`AutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();`

Hope this helps!